# computer reboots during cycles rendering on Blender 3.2 and 3.3

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I've recently been trying Blender and couldn't get it to render cycles without rebooting after just a few second. I tried to log information into a file (`blender &> blender.logs` ) but it seems that the reboot occurs without warnings to the program.

Blender 3.1 is rendering just fine, no matter the complexity of the scene so far.

Blender 3.3 alpha and 3.2 stable do reboot on the most basic cycles rendering (the cube). This occurs on CPU and GPU rendering within 5 seconds, constantly, no exceptions.

I have an i9, gigabyte motherboard and an Nvidia RTX 3060 (510, proprietary drivers). I run Ubuntu 22.04 but this also happened on ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Hardware wise, I've used my Nvidia card for neural network training without any issues and I've stress-tested it on a 3D benchmark without any trouble (so I could rule out power/PSU concerns).

I understand this is very little information for debugging but maybe someone knows a way for me to capture more information that would provide the community with more insights?

Thanks

Comment: Just a question for debugging purposes - are you running any overclocks at all (aside from basic memory/xmp)?

Comment: No overclocking on the CPU nor the graphic card. After 3 days of trying and reinstalling Ubuntu, this morning, 3.2 started rendering just fine... I have no clue what is going on.  Could installing 3.1 remove the bug from 3.2 somehow?